# HTML to PHP redirect for website in my root folder?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have recently moved my website to wordpress. I need to redirect my `.html` to `.php`. With my website being in the root folder, I do not want any redirects in the `.htaccess` to affect my sub folders with other sites in them.

Is there a rule to just redirect them for my specific website?

Answer (score 0):

Using the .htaccess should be the best way.

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 301 / http://mt-example.com/`

# This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/`

# Provide Specific Index Page (Set the default handler)
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Also here is a video on how to create the .htaccess and edit

[Video creaton and edition of .htaccess in wordpress](https://vimeo.com/59024639)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your root htaccess, put this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1.php [L,R]
```

This will redirect all html requests to php eg : **/file.html** to **/file.php** R is a temporary redirect flag, you can change this to **R=301** permanent redirect when you are sure the rule is working fine.